# Rotating four cylinders with one motor/actuator

Tags: motors, mechanisms, bearings, kinematics

I have a setup with 4 cylinders placed next to each other in following configuration. The cylinders are made of .2mm stainless steel. I would ideally want to rotate them along their axis using a single actuator/motor. What would be the best mechanism to do so?

I'd like to keep the cylinders as close to each other, due to space constraints. Any references would also help.

[image]

Comment: research the Ariel square four engine...

Comment: all in the same direction?

Comment: One central gear of radius large enough four gears on tops of the cylinders don't mesh with each other.

Comment: One chain (or belt, or timing belt) around all of them.  Somewhere along the chain is the gear connected to a motor.

Comment: Lovely. the chain mechanism worked really well!